# Active record custom relation (not based on FK)

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have 2 tables: *production* and *production_summary*. *production* store data about each production that is produced, sold or discarded. *production_summary* store daily summary about *production*. This is the *relevant* DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `production` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `created` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `production_summary` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `summary` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Models are generated by Gii and names respectively are: *Production* and *ProductionSummary*.

I defined relation like this:

```
class Production extends CActiveRecord
{
...
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'summary' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ProductionSummary', '', 'on' => 'summary.date = t.created' ),
    );
}
...
}
```

It's working fine when I get model:

```
$model = Production::model()->with( 'summary' )->findByPk($id);
```

But lazy loading fail with: unknown column **t.created**.  And I get it: Yii doesn't join tables while lazy loading, just querying the *ProductionSummary* table.

Using `with()` is not a problem in my case, but start to wonder what is the right way of defining this type of relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Yii 1.1.9 you can define relations this way:

```
return array(
    'summary' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ProductionSummary', array('date' => 'created')),
);
```